# Binding text via a function

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, xamarin

I am developing an app using Xamarin, and currently trying to display the screen width to the (I later plan to base sizes of certain objects off this)

I am attempting to use bindings to do this, but unfortunately it doesn't appear to work as expected. It does not throw an exception, just the label that I am attempting to bind has no text value.

I am sure I will be using bindings quite a lot during the rest of the project, so I would be greatly appreciative of any advice.

Please consider the following code:

C#:

```
using Xamarin.Forms;
using XLabs.Ioc;
using XLabs.Platform.Device;

namespace TimerStyles
{
    public partial class SavedTimesPage : ContentPage
    {
        string screenWidthText = "";

        public SavedTimesPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.screenWidth = getScreenWidth();
        }

        public string screenWidth
        {
            protected set
            {
                screenWidthText = value;
            }
            get { return screenWidthText; }
        }

        public string getScreenWidth()
        {
            var dev = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>();
            var display = dev.Display;
            double ScreenWidthInches = (double)display.Width / display.Xdpi;
            var ScreenWidth = (ScreenWidthInches.ToString());

            return ScreenWidth;
        }

        public string getScreenHeight()
        {
            var dev = Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>();
            var display = dev.Display;
            double ScreenHeightInches = (double)display.Height / display.Ydpi;
            var ScreenHeight = (ScreenHeightInches.ToString());

            return ScreenHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:TimerStyles="clr-namespace:TimerStyles;assembly=TimerStyles"
             x:Class="TimerStyles.SavedTimesPage"
             NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="false">

  <ContentPage.Content>  
    <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#232224">
      <Label Text="x" TextColor="Blue" FontSize="Large"/>
      <Label Text="{Binding screenWidth}" TextColor="Blue" FontSize="Large"/>
      <Label Text="x" TextColor="Blue" FontSize="Large"/>

    </StackLayout>   
  </ContentPage.Content> 

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: did you specify the BindingContext?

Comment: I doubt it, how would one do that?

Comment: see this one https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_binding_basics/

Comment: Thank you for the link, I am going through it now. Would I be correct in adding the bindingdata on the label element? And if so, what should it be set to, I have tried SavedtimesPage but alas, it throws an unhandled exception when running

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was solved by creating a "view-model" class to act as an intermediary between the view and the model, as per the following link:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data_bindings_to_mvvm/

(Obtained by following further on the link given in comments by cristallo)

Hopefully this will help anyone in the space-age future with the same issue.